# add-hook to emacs scratch at startup

Tags: emacs, scheme, elisp

I have set the emacs *scratch* to open in scheme-mode, I am running xscheme which means that when I run the command `M-x run-scheme` I can use the scratch buffer to evaluate scheme and not elisp.

```
;;(setq initial-scratch-message "")
(setq initial-major-mode 'scheme-mode)
(require 'xscheme)

;;(add-hook '**CAN I ADD A HOOK HERE?**-hook
;;    (lambda ()
;;      (run-scheme)))
```

I would like to automatically `run-scheme` on startup instead of having to type it in, but my attempts so far have not got me fo far.

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Does it work to simply put `(run-scheme)` at the top level of your .emacs?

Comment: @JonO It thows an error and has trouble opening the init file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely un-tested:

```el
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'my-scratch-run-scheme)
(defun my-scratch-run-scheme ()
  (with-current-buffer "*scratch*"
    (run-scheme))) ;; or perhaps (call-interactively 'run-scheme)
```

Comment: Thats the ticket! -- `call-interactively`.

Answer (score 2):

I put this in my init

```
;; hooks
;; startup
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (helm-mode t)
            (visual-line-mode t)
            (pomodoro-start 25))) ; 25 is minutes for work
```

If I don't add helm-mode to `emacs-startup-hook`, I need to run `M-x helm-mode` everytime I start emacs. And [pomodoro](https://github.com/baudtack/pomodoro.el/blob/master/pomodoro.el) to remind me to take a rest.